# Cartoon about a boy who regularly goes into a library and gets transported to another world, where he fights monsters along with a boy and a girl

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember seeing this show 4-5 years ago.

It was about a boy, in the process of saving his grandfather or someone, who goes into a library regularly and gets transported to another world, where he fights monsters along with a boy and a girl. After defeating the monsters, the boy captures them using a torch like thing and puts them into a book.

Comment: Almost certainly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251514/20774 - *Mad Hatter Chronicles*

Comment: @Jayati - Are you the same user who posted this [near-identical question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/280316/122024) two months ago, using a different account with the same name? If so, we'd be grateful if you'd merge your accounts by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will enable you to comment in the other thread and confirm whether the answer posted there is correct or not.